# Why can't I change the style of all li elements inside an unsorted list using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, styles, padding

I tried to change the top padding for every item in my list, but it didn't affected them at all, I want to do this when the browser being used is Internet Explorer. I tried the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.NET') !== -1) {
    $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', '10px');
}
```

Is this the correct way to change the style of an element inside another element in JQuery? If so, why it isn't affecting the list items?

This is how my HTML for the list looks like:

```
        <div id="eventTickerDiv">
            <ul id="eventTicker">
            </ul>
            <div id="hideTickerDiv"></div>
        </div>
```

This is how a list item looks like:

```
<li>Date - 2013/04/22, 16:58:32,<br/> Device - DEM002,<br/> Acceleration - 203.34,<br/> Intensity - 21</li>
```

The function where I'm trying to set the change in style is the following one:

```
function initializeEventTicker() {
    isTickerShown = true;
    //this animates the div that contains the list
    $('#eventTickerDiv').gx
        (
            {
                'height': '95%',
            },
            1000,

            'Linear',
            function (el) {

            }
        );
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.NET') !== -1) {
        $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-right', '10');
    }
    // this initiates an animation for the list to make it look like it's looping it's contents
    $('#eventTicker').totemticker({
        row_height: '160px',
        next: null,
        previous: null,
        stop: null,
        start: null,
        mousestop: true,
        speed: 800,
        interval : 2000
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is one of many ways.  What does your HTML code look like?

Comment: like this `<div id="eventTickerDiv"><ul id="eventTicker"></ul></div>` I fill the list with Javascript.

Comment: is it `eventTicker` or `eventoTicker`? Typo?

Comment: Not really worth a whole answer space, but maybe looking at [this jsFiddle I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Zvd3C/) might help?

Comment: it was a typo on my side, but still the padding doesn't change on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Went ahead and made my comment an answer and also included a fun "timer" that will show the list "breathing". Tested on IE, FF, Chrome and Safari. 0 problems. Side note, timer takes 10 seconds to kick in.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use conditional comments to serve IE specific padding adjustments?

Comment: I guess not, but I don't like to have stuff like that on my HTML, I prefer a CSS or Javascript alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should post more HTML or double check your ID names. I used the ID name you gave and have no problem making this function work ... even in IE!

Your code as written `$('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', '10px');` appears perfectly correct.

See example @:

## JSFIDDLE

```
$("#selChange").on("change", function(e) {
    $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', $(this).val());
});
```

To double check your select is firing:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.NET') !== -1) {
    // $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', '10px'); change this line to:
    console.log("Get Li Length:\t", $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', '10px').length);
    // if you ever see a "0" in the console, then this select is missfiring
}
```

### If this is a "timing" issue:

```
//  Test if this is a timing issue by placing what's in your IF statement in a Timer, 
//    If it fires this way, then you know the issue is simple:
//      Your li's are not being added to DOM till AFTER the IF statement is fired, 
//      in which case you may want to rethink "where" you call the IF statement
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('.NET') !== -1) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#eventTicker li').css('padding-top', '10px'); }, 2000);
    // This timer is set at 2 seconds (2000 in param there) and should give PLENTY of time to KNOW the LI's are Loaded in the DOM
    // If this works, for a temp solution (till you find better place for if statement)
    //    you could lower the time from 2000 to 100 and probably get same result without interference to your page as is
}
```

Comment: still, any attemp at changing the style like this is completely ignored, I get the same result in Chrome and Firefox, I don't understand why is being ignored, I check my IDs and they're the same. I don't see any exception or error message being thrown in either of the developer consoles.

Comment: is there a different way to specify to the browser to use a different padding or any other style depending on if it's IE, Chrome, etc?

Comment: @UrielArvizu Solve one thing at a time. First, I know that fiddle works, so pull it up in different browsers and ensure it works for you. If it's not working you may have JS disabled. Second, did you put your JS in `<script>` tags? and are you using `$(function() {` ready statement to wrap your JS?

Comment: The fiddle is working, I've tested it in different browsers as you mentioned. About having Javacript disabled, that's not the case since there're other operations performed in Javascript that are being done with no problem, but that line is being ignored for some reason, check the code of the function where I'm trying to do this, it shouldn't have any problem too.

Comment: My next guess would be that your selector is incorrect in some way. Easy test, open your console, highlight and copy the selector **exactly** as you have it in your code(ex: `$('#eventTicker li')`). Paste it in console then run it. If it returns an empty object, there you go, otherwise, I think your if statement might be next place to check. In which case, put `console.log("here boss!") as first line in your if statement. If you see that in console, then you know your if statement is working.

Comment: the selector is correct, I got the following:

p.fn.p.init[0]
context: document
length: 0
prevObject: p.fn.p.init[1]
0: document
context: document
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
selector: "#eventTicker li"
__proto__: Object[0]

and the if is working too, I don't really understand the reason this line is being ignored and don't know where else to look at.

Comment: It still looks like your selector is missing. You shouldn't have gotten "2 length" returns. It should have been 1 length return and it should be at least "1" always, unless it's selecting nothing. What browser console did you use to see that?

Comment: See my answer edit. Double check that select just one more time, then we'll scratch our heads on something else

Comment: I got a 0 in that line, what should I do in this case?

Comment: @UrielArvizu Now we're cooking with bacon! Ok, there is one of 2 things wrong (Probably #2). {1} The select statement is wrong. I believe solved this, but just in case, open your page in a browser with a good console. Then type `$('#eventTicker li').length` in the console AFTER you KNOW those li's exist. The length should be `> 0`, in which case. {2} This is a timing issue. What I mean is, your if statement is firing BEFORE the li's are actually added to the DOM (I assume you're adding them dynamically). If this is the case, please see revised answer ending I'm about to add.

Comment: @UrielArvizu Answer updated, take a look, have a try, test comment, what nots and what not ... lol, we'll get this figured out eventually

Comment: yeah, it's a timing issue, now the problem is that the list contents are being replaced periodically so the change in style isn't applied to the new elements added, how can I make so all of the new elements get the new style set in them?

Comment: @UrielArvizu For that operation, you'll have to do it when the li is created. Can I ask, why you havn't just added the padding when the li is created? Is there some inherent "effect" you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have the padding, the thing is in IE the styles look way different than it does in Chrome or Firefox, the fonts look bigger, the padding is bigger, everything looks like it has a different CSS, I was trying to change this with Javascript but came across the problem I described in my question, so I don't know what other options I have or if there's a way to specify in my CSS file to use different values if in IE.

Comment: @UrielArvizu OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHH! See here! http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/
Keep in mind, you dont just have to use `link` between IE if statements, you can use `style` tags as well

Comment: ok, thanks, guess I have to create another CSS for IE only then

Comment: @UrielArvizu That is the downside to making a site IE compatible. :-(